# Using setjessiecode of jsxgraph

Tags: jsxgraph

Using `setjessie` of `jsxgraph` to handle angle label. Is there any property `setjessiecode` using which we can handle this case.
[image: This image has labels with overlapping labels]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if I understand the question right. Especially, I'm not aware of the method `setjessie`. But here is an example, how to display the value of an angle instead of its name:

```
var A = board.create('point', [0, 0]);
var B = board.create('point', [3, 0]);
var C = board.create('point', [2, 3]);

var alpha = board.create('angle', [B, A, C], {
    radius: 1,
    name: function() { return JXG.Math.Geometry.trueAngle(B, A, C).toFixed(1) + '°'; }
});
```

See it in action at https://jsfiddle.net/yj7mhvk1/